# Security recommendations around granting 'Sites.FullControl' permission to Azure pipeline (Service connection object)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

i am implementing CI/CD pipeline that needs to register an AAD Application with permissions to read/write into Site collections, this would mean that the pipeline itself need to have permission to 'Sites.FullControl.All'.  I want to understand from the security perspective, if this is desirable, i.e., a pipeline having FullControl access to a SharePoint tenant.  What are the recommended practices w.r.t. this, will the application registration in such scenarios be manually done by Ops team?

Comment: Have you tried the service connection with Full Control access to SharePoint tenant?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that you want to use the service connection in the Azure CI/CD pipeline.

We can create a service connection with Service principal (automatic) or Service principal (manual).

Use the following parameters to define and secure a connection to a Microsoft Azure subscription using Service Principal Authentication (SPA) or an Azure managed Service Identity.

- Automated subscription detection. In this mode, Azure Pipelines
  queries Azure for all of the subscriptions and instances to which you
  have access. They use the credentials you're currently signed in with
  in Azure Pipelines (including Microsoft accounts and School or Work
  accounts).

If you don't see the subscription you want to use, sign out of Azure Pipelines and sign in again using the appropriate account credentials.

- Manual subscription pipeline. In this mode, you must specify the
  service principal you want to use to connect to Azure. The service
  principal specifies the resources and the access levels that are
  available over the connection.

For more information, you could refer to [Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection).

Comment: My question is related to the security practices.  Is it recommended to have service-connection with FullControl access to SharePoint tenant tenant (broadly, this can apply to AAD itself)?  I wanted to know the opinions about this from Ops team.  Thanks.

Comment: Based on my experience, you can have service connection with full control access to SharePoint tenant, this can apply to ADD.